# Determine the font family name of encrypted fonts used in a pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts

My company currently implements fillable reports when submitting documents. Now we are in the process of converting these fillable forms into computerized one, although the user still has the option to print the report if they need it to be. The company had given me the PDF file of the fillable report to be converted as my template. And I had managed to translate it exactly the way it looked, but for one aspect: the font.

When I checked what font are used in the PDF (via Adobe Reader), it gave me this:

[image]

What does TTE252C168t00 mean? Is it some equivalent for Arial? I can identify some fonts on the PDF as Arial Narrow, or some other common fonts, but what about the other nine fonts in this PDF that is identified with the same cryptic naming pattern? How can I determine the names of these fonts? Or does this means my pdf is corrupted (this pdf template was made last 2005, 12 years ago)?

What I have tried:

1. Use other PDF readers.
2. Copy the text and paste it into MS-Office Word, but the PDF is protected.

Comment: There are several sites where you can upload an image and it tries to identify the font for you. E.g. [this](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: As it says ["Embedded subset"](http://community.zmags.com/articles/Knowledgebase/Difference-between-full-embedded-fonts-and-embedded-subset-1277814749518) my guess would be that it's an automatically generated name. Find a similar font and use it or ask for the original, unprotected source document for those PDFs.